# Json string number format

Tags: javascript, json, floating-point, numbers, conventions

I try to understand JSON strings better. Especially numbers in that format.

Checking if a JSON string is a [valid number](https://www.json.org/img/number.png) is easy (as described later), but what are the conventions for parsing a number to a JSON string?

The number `5` can be easily parsed to `"5"`, but should I parse `5000` to `"5000"`, to `"5e3"` or to `"5E3"`?

Is there a widely accepted (conventions?) minimum/maximum bound for numbers which are too small/too big such that we use `e`?

And a second question on this topic: how would I check if the JSON string stores an integer value. This question arises because `"5e-2"` is `0.05`. The string doesn't contain `"."` but is still a fraction, which is non trivial. Of course I could do it with simply parsing the value with `Number()` (JavaScript) and checking if it is an integer with `Number.isInteger()` (JavaScript). But that doesn't help me to understand it really better. Could I check if the string contains `"e-"`/`"E-"`, then check if the following number is bigger than the number of digits before the `"."`/`"e"`/`"E"`?

To check if a JSON string is a valid number (not integer), I use this regex in JavaScript:

```
// JavaScript
const isJsonNumberRegex = /^-?(?:0|[1-9]\d*)(?:\.\d*)?(?:[eE][+-]?\d+)?$/m;

function isJsonNumber(n: string): boolean {
    return n.match(isJsonNumberRegex) !== null;
}
```

The string can start with `"-"`, then comes a single `0` **or** a digit `1-9`, then optionally followed by any amount of digits `0-9`. If it is a fraction, it is followed by a `"."` and then by any amount of digits `0-9`. To use exponents it starts by the character `"e"` or `"E"`, is optionally followed by `"+"` or `"-"`, and then again any amount of digits `0-9`.

For example:

```js
function isJsonNumber(n){
    return n.match(/^-?(?:0|[1-9]\d*)(?:\.\d*)?(?:[eE][+-]?\d+)?$/m) !== null;
}

console.log(isJsonNumber("-12.34E+56")); // true
console.log(isJsonNumber("0.0e-010")); // true

console.log(isJsonNumber("+0")); // false
console.log(isJsonNumber(".5")); // false
console.log(isJsonNumber("a")); // false
```

Answer (score 0):

The specification for JSON can be found here: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4627#section-2.4

Copy of what is said in the above link:

> The representation of numbers is similar to that used in most
> programming languages.  A number contains an integer component that
> may be prefixed with an optional minus sign, which may be followed by
> a fraction part and/or an exponent part.

Therefore, your test should work per these specifications.

Comment: Thanks! But that wasn't really the question xD